# Configuring serial port touch screen in lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen

I've successfully installed lubuntu 18.04, recommended for my FOSS [POS program](https://logic-pos.com/?page_id=2279&lang=en) to run in a Snack-Bar, in a pretty old, but 100% functional Sam4s machine ([hardware description link](http://www.posregister.com/pos_spt4700.htm)) .
Everything works smooth but the touch screen is not auto-detected neither appear in the xinput result as follow:

```
    $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The touch screen is connected through an internal serial port.

By using evtest to try all inputs, I get no touch screen response from none of these:

```
    $ sudo evtest
[sudo] senha para burguesa: 
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event5:  PixArt USB Optical Mouse
/dev/input/event6:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event7:  HDA Intel Mic
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel Line
/dev/input/event9:  HDA Intel Line Out
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Select the device event number [0-10]:
```

Can someone please give me some hints to help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the touch screen manufacturer produce a Linux driver? You likely need one to get it to work.

Comment: I coulnd't find none, Only for windows. But it has been working on a linux operating system, so there is a way around. On the old installation I am still looking for hints in config files, but found nothing yet.

Comment: You haven't said which Lubuntu ISO you installed your OS with. Did you use one with the GA kernel? (ie. 18.04, 18.04.1) or one with the HWE kernel (18.04.2 media or later). If it's a newer touch screen, you may have more luck with the HWE (hardware enablement) stack active. Also don't forget Lubuntu being a *flavor* comes only with 3 years of *full* support (till 2021-April)

Comment: It was the lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso. Do you think I should upgrade? The thing is that the program I need to run was too buggy with Lubuntu 20.04, which I have tried before. And it didn't recognized my old hardware either.

Comment: You can switch post-install (easiest to go from GA to HWE), without re-install. Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  The GA kernel is 4.15, where with HWE you'll use the 5.4 kernel found in 20.04 which should provide later drivers for more modern hardware. If you tried Lubuntu 20.04 and it didn't recognize your hardware any better, it's unlikely to help (as HWE uses the later stack found in 20.04)  A quick look and the POS software looks to be GTK based (*GTK runtime required on windows anyway*)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.In the meantime I discovered I have an ELO touchscreen and found the solution with a linux driver made by them.
It took me a week to find it here https://assets.ctfassets.net/of6pv6scuh5x/34ScEVkSHs935IZhTnZBJ0/8c17e8307ed005e353773147c8064780/Elo-Linux-Serial-Driver-v3.4.0_Installation-Instructions.txt

Comment: Thanks for providing link  (*I have ELO (POS) touchscreen here, but I only use it as a screen so never explored further*).  When you get it working, please consider writing up an answer here so others may benefit.  Well done & thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. To solve the problem I just followed the steps described on this link. The only thing you need to discover by yourself is the the serial port on which the screen is internally connected. But you can get there by trying. In my case it's ttyS1.

Comment: Please write it as an answer below (not as comment). The original poster (you) can in time accept the answer so you'll gain REP for this (& SE) sites (you can't accept immediately, but later). I can also upvote (more rep for you), as answered questions are more readily found (not deleted as problem went away; comments commonly are deleted)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I followed the steps described on this link that leads to the [ELO Touchscreen manufacturer driver page](https://assets.ctfassets.net/of6pv6scuh5x/34ScEVkSHs935IZhTnZBJ0/8c17e8307ed005e353773147c8064780/Elo-Linux-Serial-Driver-v3.4.0_Installation-Instructions.txt).

The only thing you need to discover by yourself is the the serial port on which the screen is internally connected. If not sure, you can get there by attempting starting at ttyS0, ttyS1 and so on. In my case it is ttyS1.

Comment: A summary of the steps (somewhat copy & paste, from your command `history` maybe) would have been much better, as your answer will be meaningless if the web page is removed.